# C++ struct template variable shortcut definition does not work

Tags: c++

```
template <class T>
Struct st
{
   ... 
} a<T>;
```

Doesnt work althogh non template shortcut works how ia tge right way to do the template shorycut?

Comment: What are you expecting `a` to be after this declaration?

Comment: For example, you also write `std::vector<int> x;` not `std::vector x<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ grammar generally lets you do `type name;` to declare a variable, where `type` is a type and `name` is a name.  The syntax `struct foo { }` is considered a type by the grammar, which makes `struct foo { } bar;` legal (declare a type named `foo` and a variable of type `foo` with the name `bar`).

However, in your example, `st` is **not actually a type** but rather a *type template.*

Type templates aren't types in their own right; they're "recipes" for the compiler to automatically create types on demand.  `st<int>` is a type, but `st` by itself isn't.

Because of this, the shortcut is not grammatically correct, and is nonsensical when you think about it.  You can't declare a variable of something that isn't a type.  The workaround would be to simply not use the shortcut and declare a variable separately.